# Scroll down at the bottom of a webpage (selenium/python)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scroll

I am trying to get all the images from this webpage: "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/43871809/photos?guests=1&adults=1"

I am using XPath to get all the images but if I don't scroll down at the bottom then XPath only gets 13 images when it should get 39.
I am using the following code:

```
   s = Service('D:\Selenium driver\chromedriver2.exe')
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
   url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/43871809/photos?guests=1&adults=1'
   driver.get(url)
   time.sleep(4)
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1oaklsk"]/div/div/picture/img')
```

I am other methods to create scroll action. But I think the problem lies with the page. Can anyone provide me a solution with the scrolling or any other method getting all the 39 images.

P.S: I am new at this and still learning and I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below `xpath` and it returned **39** as the count of the images.

```
//div[@data-testid='photo-viewer-section']//a
```

**The code:**

```
#Imports Required:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/43871809/photos?guests=1&adults=1")

images_count = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='photo-viewer-section']//a")

print(len(images_count))
```

**Output:**

```
39
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful accept the same. Click on the right option available for the answer

Comment: @Tanvir - You need reputation to upvote not to accept the answer. [Link to refer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)